# restart a program in C when "if" is used

Tags: c, restart

I continue to learn programming in C, and today I met a problem. 
In my program, a user must enter a value of time in minutes, and my program will calculate it seconds(very simple, actually). But I want to set a rule, that time cannot be negative. So I used this code:

```
    if(a<=0)
    {
        printf("Time cannot be equal to, or smaller than zero, so the program will now terminate\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

but now, I don`t want to terminate my program, I want it to return to the state when a user has to enter a value.

I had a problem with terminating my program, but some search helped me, however I did not get any result searching how to restart my program.

This is the text of my program(I am working on Linux):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
    float a;
    printf("\E[36m");
    printf("This program will convert minutes to seconds");
    getchar();
    printf("Now enter your time in minutes(e.g. 5):");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("As soon as you will press the Enter button you`ll get your time in seconds\n");
    getchar();
    getchar();


    if(a<=0)
    {
        printf("Time cannot be equal to, or smaller than zero, so the program will now terminate\n");
        printf("\E[0m");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        float b;
        b=a*60;
        printf("\E[36m");
        printf("The result is %f seconds\n", b);
        printf("Press Enter to finish\n");
        getchar();
    }
    printf("\E[0m");
}
```

P.S. I don`t know how to correctly name this function, so I call it restart, maybe it has a different name?

Comment: Use a loop with `a <= 0` for its terminating condition.

Comment: An idea: keep reading input `while` the program has not get a valid input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the solutions that have been posted work, but I personally like this approach better:

```
// ...
printf("Now enter your time in minutes(e.g. 5):");
scanf("%f", &a);

while(a <= 0){
   printf("Time cannot be equal to, or smaller than zero, please enter again: ");
   scanf("%f", &a);
}
```

I think it is more clear, and it gives the opportunity to have an error message and a regular message independent of each other.

Comment: thanks, just a second, I'm trying it.
looks like I understood what for 'while' is used

Comment: THANKS!!!! It worked, and I understood why(I think it's the most important thing :D)

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help, and you're right, understanding why is the most important thing! Happy coding :)

Comment: one more question... which way I can increase your reputation? :D
upps, I did it already :D and I understood it too :D

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `do ... while` loop (including your program source code).

```
do {
    /* Get user input. */
} while (a <= 0);
```

Or the `goto` statement too to emulate a loop (discouraged with beginners).

```
 start:
    /* Get user input. */
    if (a <= 0)
        goto start;
```

Comment: first way I think is another type of 'if'? because it says 'do' /this/ while 'the input is invalid'

Comment: but I need to return to the state where you have to enter a value, 'if' the input is invalid

Comment: So, it seems to be right. You can translate this `do ... while` loop with : "While the input is invalid, enter a value".

Answer (score 0):

you could try if-else where:

```
do
{
/* get user input*/
if (a > 0)
    {
     /* ... */
    }
else
   printf ("Time cannot be negative, please re-enter") 
}while(<condition>);
```

*condition may be until when you want to continue.

Comment: interesting solution, will try it now. but I would be very happy, if there is a way to make program to ask you to enter a value again after an invalid input

Comment: i have updated the code.You could just get the user input within the do while loop before checking for the condition.

Comment: please, look to my code in first post, I want to replace 'exit(EXIT_FAILURE)' with a code that will make program to ask you to enter a value again

Comment: This will make the program to ask for the value until your while condition is false.